# Continuous and discrete variables with OpenTURNS

Tags: python, random, statistics, uncertainty, openturns

How to create a design of experiments with both continuous and discrete random variables with OpenTURNS?

I get that we can do:

```
X0 = ot.Normal()
X1 = ot.Normal()
distribution  = ot.ComposedDistribution([X0,X1])
```

But this creates only a  continuous joint distribution, from which I can sample from. But how to create a joint distribution of a continuous and a discrete variable? Can I sample from it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in general, OpenTURNS does not make much difference between continuous and discrete distributions. So, once we have created a `Distribution`, all we have to do is to use the `getSample` method to get a simple Monte-Carlo sample. The following example shows that we can push the idea a little further by creating a LHS design of experiments.

To create the first marginal of the distribution, we select a univariate discrete distribution. Many  of them, like the `Bernoulli` or `Geometric` distributions, are implemented in the library. In this example we pick the `UserDefined` distribution that assigns equal weights to the values -2, -1, 1 and 2.
Then we create a Monte-Carlo experiment first with the `getSample` method and then with the `MonteCarloExperiment` method. Any other type of design of experiments can be generated based on this distribution and this is why we finally show how to create a LHS (Latin Hypercube) experiment.

```
import openturns as ot
sample = ot.Sample([-2., -1., 1., 2.],1)
X0 = ot.UserDefined(sample)
X1 = ot.Normal()
distribution = ot.ComposedDistribution([X0,X1])
# Monte-Carlo experiment, simplest version
sample = distribution.getSample(10)
print(sample)
# Monte-Carlo experiment
size = 100
experiment = ot.MonteCarloExperiment(distribution, size)
sample = experiment.generate()
```

The following script produces the associated graphics.

```
graph = ot.Graph("MonteCarloExperiment", "x0", "x1", True, "")
cloud = ot.Cloud(sample, "blue", "fsquare", "")
graph.add(cloud)
graph
```

The previous script prints:

```
    [ v0         X0         ]
0 : [  2         -0.0612243 ]
1 : [  1          0.789099  ]
2 : [ -1          0.583868  ]
3 : [ -1          1.33198   ]
4 : [ -2         -0.934389  ]
5 : [  2          0.559401  ]
6 : [ -1          0.860048  ]
7 : [  1         -0.822009  ]
8 : [  2         -0.548796  ]
9 : [ -1          1.46505   ]
```

and produces the following graphics:

[image: Mixed discrete and continuous sample]

It is straightforward to create a LHS on the same distribution.

```
size = 100
experiment = ot.LHSExperiment(distribution, size)
sample = experiment.generate()
```